# How to set the alpha value for each element of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, matplotlib

I want to populate an array and then show it like an image. I want to set two parameters for each array element: a "color value" and a "transparency value".
I am using imshow from matplotlib, but I am open to other solutions.
I have tried with something like this, where ca_map is a MxN array.

```
ca_map = np.array(ca_map)

palette = cm.jet
palette.set_under('w', 1.0)

plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(ca_map, cmap=palette, norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=0, clip=False), interpolation='sinc')
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs ( http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow ) say that you can pass an MxNx4 array of RGBA values to imshow. So, assuming ca_map is MxNx3, you could do something like:

```
plt.imshow(np.dstack([ca_map, alpha], ...)
```

Or if ca_map is MxN, then:

```
plt.imshow(np.dstack([ca_map, ca_map, ca_map, alpha], ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately ca_map is a MxN array. I have just edited my question to add that information.

Answer (score 1):

Luke's answer is good for MxNx3, but for MxN cases his solution will give you shades of gray (equal rgb values) for your image. If you wanted any kind of colour in the image, the following might be helpful:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

data = numpy.arange(12.).reshape(3, 4)

import matplotlib.colors
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(data.min(), data.max())


img_array = plt.get_cmap('jet')(norm(data))
print img_array.shape
img_array[..., 3] = 1 - (norm(data)/2)  # <- some alpha values between 0.5-1

plt.imshow(img_array)
plt.show()
```